# How to treat char as char in _generic in c

Tags: c, generics

I a working on designing a generic queue

https://github.com/Bhaumik-Tandan/Generic_queue_in_c

But i am facing a problem when I am  creating a generic fucntion enqueue for all types of
data types

```
#define enqueue(s,a) _Generic(a, int: enqueuei__19BIT0292, char*: enqueues__19BIT0292,double: enqueuef__19BIT0292,char:enqueuec__19BIT0292,float:enqueuef__19BIT0292)(s,a)
```

The bellow line treats 'c' as int and call the respective function.

```
enqueue(s,'c')
```

Whereas if I want to call function of char, I need to write

```
enqueue(s,(char)'c')
```

I know in C characters are internally treated as integers, but is there any way to tackle this, I don't want to write (char) in the brackets or create a new variable each time I pass a character

Comment: I'd say no. `'c'` is no different from `99` (assuming ASCII)

Comment: Using `enqueue(s, *"c")` saves 5 characters over typing a cast. Otherwise, I don't think it's possible.

Comment: From [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal): _In C, character constants such as 'a' or '\n' have type int, rather than char."_ It's an `int` by definition, so I don't see a way around that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a macro that tests if argument is a `char` *(starts with `'`)* like this:

```
#define is_char_literal(c) (#c[0] == '\'')
```

then you can use a ternal

```
#define enqueue(s,a) is_char_literal(a)? enqueuec__19BIT0292(s,a): __Generic(a, int: enqueuei__19BIT0292, char*: enqueues__19BIT0292,double: enqueuef__19BIT0292, char:enqueuec__19BIT0292, float:enqueuef__19BIT0292)(s,a)
```

and depend on the compiler, if your compiler supports optimization by *"const"* evaluation

Comment: This is interesting approach. Adding extra code and data overhead though

Comment: Very clever! It will break for `enqueue(s, ('a'))`, but that's an odd notation anyway.

Comment: it will behave differently for `enqueue(s, 'a'+1)` and `enqueue(s, 1+'a')`. Personally, I would avoid such a trap.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. according to [https://godbolt.org/](https://godbolt.org/) in GCC with -O3 flag it doesn't add any additional overhead

Comment: @tstanisl well if you add int and char in this order then you should definitely get an int as a result but I see what you mean

Comment: @tstanisl I would definitely avoid too, but still interesting.

Comment: I suggest renaming `ischar` to `is_char_literal`

Comment: Would using `*#c` instead of `#c[0]` work as well?

Comment: @Yun yop, `#` just converts `'c'` into `"\'c\'"`

Comment: You can safe up the macro quite a bit like this: `#define is_char_literal(c) (#c[0] == '\'' && sizeof #c == 4)`.