# Wrong char output for Generic print C

Tags: c, generics, printing, char

I have a macro with _Generic for printing

```
#define PRINT(data)                                 \
        _Generic((data),                            \
        char:print_char)(data)
```

and this is the implementation for print_char

```
void print_char(char data){
    printf("%c\n",data);
}
```

The problem is that when I call PRINT('t') for example it prints 116 instead of t, the solution I found was to add (char) in PRINT statemen like PRINT((char)'t').
The question is how can I print the char without the cast?

Comment: I actually answered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68866475/10404680) very similar to this

Comment: The code in the question does not print “116”; it contains no `printf` or other statement that would print “116”. When asking questions such as this, please ensure the code constitutes a correct [mre].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to treat char as char in \_generic in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68866475/how-to-treat-char-as-char-in-generic-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

For historical reasons, dating back to the early days when C lacked a type system and treated everything as `int`, a lot of things we would expect to be `char` are actually still `int`. There are many examples in the language:

- character literals like `'A'` are type `int`.
- `getchar` returns an `int`.
- `EOF` is an `int`.
- `ctype.h` functions use `int` not `char`.

And so on. This is a well-known language defect. C++ changed several of these defects very early on, but C insists on remaining broken even to this day.

Answer (score 0):

In C, plain character constants such as `'t'` have type `int`.

The `PRINT` macro could be changed to the following:

```
define PRINT(data)                                 \
        _Generic((data),                           \
        int:print_char)(data)
```

If it is desired that `PRINT` should do something else for a "normal" integer value, then that would not be a suitable solution.